# phoenix - what is the equivalent functionality of UPSERT VALUES..ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: upsert, apache-phoenix

I have situation where i don't want data to be updated if the data provided already exists (exact functionality of UPSERT VALUES in 4.9).

lets say this i my data and the primary key is deptno.

```
 deptno, deptname, created_date
 1       dept1     2017-03-22 00:10:30 
 2       dept2     2017-03-23 00:10:30
```

When i do upsert for dept2 as

```
upsert into dept(deptno,deptname,created_date) values(2,'new dept name','2017-04-06 00:12:30');
upsert into dept(deptno,deptname,created_date) values(3,'dept3','2017-04-06 00:12:30');
```

It shouldn't update any info for deptno 2 since it already exists. deptno 3 data should be upserted.

is there any function that i can use for the phoenix version in 4.9 has UPSERT VALUES.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what are you looking for: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_or_update/2

```
result =
  case MyRepo.get(Post, id) do
    nil  -> %Post{id: id} # Post not found, we build one
    post -> post          # Post exists, let's use it
  end
  |> Post.changeset(changes)
  |> MyRepo.insert_or_update

case result do
  {:ok, struct}       -> # Inserted or updated with success
  {:error, changeset} -> # Something went wrong
end
```